# What is the meaning of 'next days'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I am working with company in Germany. I requested some documents, and they replied that they will send it 'next days'. What is meaning of 'next days'? I confused because of 'days'. Does it meaning within following next few days? or Tomorrow?

Answer (score 2):

APthree's answer is correct.  In German, it's "[in den nächsten Tagen](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/was-versteht-man-unter-in-den-naechsten-tagen)." It sounds like somebody's English wasn't too good, and they translated poorly. The page I have cited also wondered how many days it meant, exactly.  The answer was 2-4 days.

Comment: Thank you Wordster. Now I am clear with meaning. I will wait 2-4 days more :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what they said was a typo, because there is no way the sentence you said could be correct with “next” beside “days”. Assuming the sentence was “We will send it next days”, correct options include:

- We will send it in the **next** few **days**.
- We will have sent it within the **next** few **days**.
- We will send it in the **next day**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much APthree. I haven't got any feed back yet, so it might be next few days:) It also help me a lot to improve my writing!